# LDAP long message length representation

Tags: c++, ldap, asn.1

I'm dissecting messages in LDAP client-server communication and having trouble understand how the message length is calculated.

Based on LDAP standards, when communicating in ASN.1 each message begins with `0x30` *(ldap message start)* and following bytes should be the message length *(or number or relevant bytes that follow)* up untill there is `0x2` and `0x1` signalling the message ID. This is clear.

In short messages it can look something like this:

```
0x30    (start),
0x3c    (length),
0x2     (msg id..
0x1
0x1     ),
...
```

with length being `0x3c` or simply `60` in DEC, and the number of following bytes untill the end of the message **is** in fact 60.

Slightly longer message can look like this:

```
0x30    (start),
0x81    (???),
0x8e    (length),
0x2     (msg id..
0x1
0x1     ),
...
```

with length again exactly at `0x8e` (or `142` in DEC), but what does the previous byte mean?

Even longer message look like this:

```
0x30    (start),
0x82    (???),
0x2     (???),
0xe3    (???),
0x2     (msg id..
0x1
0x1     ),
...
```

with neither `0x82`, `0x2` or `0xe3` (or `130`, `2` or `227` in DEC) being the actual length (that is in fact 739)

and I can't see the logic between the two last examples. How is the length presented in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of encoding lengths in ASN.1 - the definite form, and the indefinite form.

For the definite form, if the length is less than 128, you just use a single byte, with the high bit set to zero. Otherwise the high bit is set to one, and the low seven bits set to the length of length. The length is then encoded in that many bytes (in big endian order).

`0x82` has a high bit of 1 and the remaining bits equal to 2, meaning the following 2 bytes contain the length (0x02E3 = 739).

Comment: I see, thank you, that's exactly what I wanted to know.